Spring JPA deleteById not deleting entity
I'm attempting to delete a Character object, but all attempts at doing so fail.
The relevant classes are:
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHARACTERS")
class CharacterEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID", nullable = false)
    val bank: BankEntity,
    @Column(nullable = true)
    val playerId: Long?,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    val name: String,
    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = [ALL], mappedBy = "character", orphanRemoval = true)
    val accounts: MutableList<AccountEntity> = mutableListOf()
) {
    @OneToOne(fetch = EAGER, cascade = [ALL], mappedBy = "character", orphanRemoval = true)
    val downtimeOverride: DowntimeOverride = DowntimeOverride(0, this)
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS")
class AccountEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHARACTER_ID", nullable = false)
    val character: CharacterEntity,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    val accountType: AccountTypeEntity,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [DETACH])
    val logs: MutableList<LogEntity> = mutableListOf(),
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var balance: Double = 0.0
) 

@Entity
@EntityListeners(LogService::class)
@Table(name = "LOGS")
class LogEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID", nullable = true)
    val account: AccountEntity?,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    val description: String,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    val balance: Double,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    val timestamp: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now()
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOWNTIME_OVERRIDE")
class DowntimeOverride(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    val id: Long,
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHARACTER_ID", nullable = false)
    val character: CharacterEntity,
    @Column(nullable = true)
    var times: Int? = null,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = true)
    var frequency: Frequency? = null,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = true)
    var denomination: Denomination? = null,
    @Column(nullable = true)
    var multiplier: Double? = null,
    @Column(nullable = true)
    var baseDice: String? = null
)

I have attempted both the default characterRepository.delete and characterRepository.deleteById, as well as trying accountRepository.deleteAll and accountRepository.deleteById to delete the accounts before deleting the characters. None of which appear to do anything.
These are called from within a @Transactional method, and I flush the repositories immediately after deleting.
I have additionally attempted the following override:
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from CharacterEntity where id = ?1")
    override fun deleteById(id: Long)

Which yields the following exception:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: JDBC exception executing SQL [delete from characters where id=?] [Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKJP0EAS7BJKVDK8DMABC92PRK3: PUBLIC.ACCOUNTS FOREIGN KEY(CHARACTER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CHARACTERS(ID) (CAST(2 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
delete from characters where id=? [23503-224]] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKJP0EAS7BJKVDK8DMABC92PRK3: PUBLIC.ACCOUNTS FOREIGN KEY(CHARACTER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CHARACTERS(ID) (CAST(2 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
delete from characters where id=? [23503-224]]


You're facing a foreign key constraint violation, so either adapt the cascade or better, remove all references pointing to CharacterEntity first. But to be honest, the exception tells you this exactly, so you could have come to this conclusion by yourself^^.

@Slevin Adapt the cascade how? I do intend for the delete to cascade down to the AccountEntities and DowntimeOverride that reference the CharacterEntity, but to my understanding that is already supposed to happen under cascade = [ALL].

Got it working by removing the characters from the collections associating them to the banks instead, and then saving the banks.
Not an ideal solution, and it complicates the code, but at least it works.
A solution that would configure JPA such that the repositories work properly would be preferable. But it is technically a solution, and any solution is better than none. So answering this with my own workaround in case some poor bastard stumbles upon this.
